# An optional dict in the structure with MongoKit

Tags: python, mongodb, mongokit

I've got MongoKit structure like this:

```
structure = {
  ...

  'plugin': {
    'id': unicode,
    'title': unicode,
    'description': unicode,

  ...
}
```

However, not all documents will have the `plugin` key. If they do, I'd like it to be validated against the structure.

`required_fields` does *not* include `plugin`. (`plugin` isn't a required key.)

I've tried `'plugin': OR(None, {...})`, but `OR` doesn't like `None` as a value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in 0.5:

> http://bitbucket.org/namlook/mongokit/issue/78/not-required-fields-wrongly-validates#comment-234872

Discussion and temporary workaround here:

> http://groups.google.com/group/mongokit/browse_thread/thread/18fe4081a306e93e